# How to show a dummy url instead ip?

Tags: html

In my application, there is a link to a ip number, but instead of it, i would like to show a dummy url, and when the user click it, he will be directionade to the ip address

This is what I have:

```
   <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 6.25%; padding-right: 6.25%; width: 87.5%; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 150%;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: #999999;
        font-family: sans-serif;" class="footer">
            http://55.55.555.555
    </td>
```

This is what I want:

```
      <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 6.25%; padding-right: 6.25%; width: 87.5%; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 150%;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: #999999;
        font-family: sans-serif;" class="footer">
                    www.anyurl.com (but it goes to http://55.55.555.555)
      </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a link; it is just text (although your browser may be interpreting it and rendering it as a clickable link).

The `A` tag is used to identify links; it has an `href` attribute which is the URL to link to, and the text between `<A>` and `</A>` can be anything you want.  SO, for your example, you would use:

```
<A href="http://55.55.555.555">www.anyurl.com</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 6.25%; padding-right: 6.25%; width: 87.5%; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 150%;
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                color: #999999;
                font-family: sans-serif;" class="footer">

<!-- this is your IP url masked with dummy url   --> 

<a href="http://55.55.555.555">www.anyurl.com</a>

 <!-- end of link code -->

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple link will do the trick

```html
<a href="http://55.55.555.555">www.anyurl.com</a>
```

This will still show up as `55.55.555.555` in the users browser though. If you want `www.anyurl.com` you will need to register `anyurl.com` at the domain broker of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide any value in between the  tags and that value will come as the name of the link.

```
<a href="http://55.55.555.555">www.anyurl.com</a>
```

is a table data element. Writing a url within  elements will not make it a link. To create a link you have to use  tag